# Bound on the distance of a normal vector

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $Z_i\sim N(0,\sigma_i^2)$, $i=1,\dots,n$ independent. I'm looking for the uniform (over $z\in \mathbb{R}_+$) bound of the following probability

$$P\{z-\epsilon\le \sqrt{\sum Z_i^2}\le z+\epsilon\}$$

in terms of $\epsilon$. If the density of $Z=\sqrt{\sum Z_i^2}$ is bounded (by $C$, say), then

$$P\{z-\epsilon\le \sqrt{\sum Z_i^2}\le z+\epsilon\}=\int_{(z-\epsilon)\vee 0}^{z+\epsilon}f_Z(x)dx\le C\epsilon.$$

Is there a way to formulate such $C$ in terms of $\sigma_i$'s, for example?